# django manytomany model relationship crashing admin on object create

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin

I have an `Event` object in my postgres db, and created a new `Collection` object to group events by theme via a ManyToMany field relationship:

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    event = models.ManyToManyField('Event', related_name='collections')
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=280)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='collection_images/', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=1000)
    theme = models.ManyToManyField('common.Tag', related_name='themes')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('collection', args=[self.slug])

    def clean(self):
        # because of the way db saves M2M relations, collection doesn't have a
        # type at this time yet, so image inheritance is
        # called from the signal which is triggered when M2M is created
        # (that means if an image is later deleted, it won't inherit a new
        # one when collection is saved)
        if self.image:
            validate_hero_image(self.image, 'image')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.full_clean()
        except ValidationError as e:
            log.error('Collection validation error (name = %s): %s' % (self.name, e))
        return super(Collection, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

in my admin, I'm defining and registering CollectionAdmin like this:

```
class CollectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Collection
    verbose_name = 'Collection'
    list_display = ( 'name', )
```

however, if I go into admin and attempt to create a Collection `"GET /admin/app/collection/add/" 200`, the request frequently times out and the query load on my database from the `Event` M2M relationship seems quite heavy from logging. For reference currently the db has ~100,000 events. are there better ways to (re)structure my admin fields so I can select specific events (by name or id) to add to a `Collection` without effectively requesting a QuerySet of all events when that view is loaded (or creating them in db via shell)? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this. For example, you could [override the form fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) the admin uses and specify another widget to use, like [`NumberInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#numberinput).

You could also add your `event` model field to the [`raw_id_fields` attribute of ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields). By doing so, Django won't try to create a fully populated select input but will offer you a way to search for events manually if needed:

```
class CollectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Collection
    verbose_name = 'Collection'
    list_display = ('name', )
    raw_id_fields = ('event', )
```

Comment: thanks Soren. `raw_id_fields` is a great field alternative for this use case